# Add inner shadow to TextView

Tags: android

I'm developing an android quiz game.

My game activity has 5 textviews (1 for the question and 4 for the answers).

The below image is the style I need to give to my TextView.

[image]

At the beginning I thought to use the image as a background but the question/answer text lenght isn't always the same so I didn't know how to adapt it to short or long text.

Is there any way to do this in XML?

Comment: Have you tried 9 patch images ?

Comment: I don't know that. Can you explain me please?

Comment: When you want to create resizable images for backgrounds, the official documentation says that you should use 9 patch images: [https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch)